# How to tell whether lone pairs in heterocycles contribute to aromaticity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds, aromaticity

How can I decide whether lone pair electrons take part in the continuous overlap of electron or not?

For example, the lone pair in pyridine is not a part of the conjugated system, whereas the lone pair in pyrrole is.

I had read that this was due to the lone pair in pyridine being localised in an sp<sup>2</sup> orbital, while the lone pair in pyrrole is delocalised.

How do we identify this?

Comment: What would it look like if the pyridine N would put its pair to the p-orbital and the remaining electron to the sp2 that points outward? A wannabe-aromatic ring with 7 electrons and a lone unpaired electron on sp2.

Comment: Related: [Why is only one lone pair in imidazole delocalised?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10870/16683); [Why is the lone pair of pyridine's nitrogen atom not part of the aromatic ring?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50266/16683)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the most common situations use this rule: a conjugated ring atom needs either a ligand or a localized electron pair to replace a missing ligand.  Any remaining electron pairs are then part of the conjugated pi system.

Thus pyridine needs a localized lone pair on nitrogen to replace a missing ligand, and that leaves only three bonding pairs for the pi system.  Pyrrole has a ligand on nitrogen so the lone pair is conjugated into the pi system along with two carbon-carbon bonds.  Furan has two lone pairs on oxygen but a missing ligand, therefore oxygen contributes one pair to the pi system.

Comment: Okay so whenever the contribution of lone pair may result in aromaticity, it will always participate in the conjugated system ? Also thanks!

Comment: The ability to form an aromatic ring is favorable, but in most cases the sigma orbital requirements come first.  Check that, then count what's left.